# syntax error during implementation of RC4 algorithm

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

I am trying to modify implementation RC4 algorithm in python that i found online  and i am getting a syntax error for using a if loop in place of while loop can anybody tell me why is that?

```
def PRGA(S):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    if i==0 & j==0:    # here it was originally while True:, so I changed it to if statement
        i = (i + 1) % 256
        j = (j + S[i]) % 256

        S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i]  # swap values
        K = S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256
        print ('K')    # and here it was yield K
    else:
        print ('error')
```

Comment: you need `&&` or `and` at your if statement not `&`; `&` is a bitwise "and" you need the logical one: `&&`

Comment: I am using python 3

Comment: when I made it to && the error shifted to where the if statement was given

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
    K = S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256
```

has an unbalanced bracket… nothing to do with *using a if loop in place of while loop*.

> i tried adding that bracket at the end and it gives me index error: list index out of range

The posted code is missing the [Key-scheduling algorithm (KSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Key-scheduling_algorithm_(KSA)) part, which *is used to initialize the permutation in the array "S".*

Comment: i tried adding that bracket at the end and it gives me index error: list index out of range